# A usage of setuid?

Tags: unix

I read a Powerpoint slide recently, and can't get a clear concept about the usage of setuid.
Here is the content of the slide.

> Setuid example - printing a file
>
> - Goals
>
>   - Every user can queue files
>   - Users cannot delete other users' files
> - Solution
>
>   - Queue directory owned by user printer
>   - Setuid queue-file program
>
>     - Create queue file as user printer
>     - Copy joe's data as user joe
>   - Also, setuid remove-file program
>
>     - Allows removal only of files you queued
>   - User printer mediated user joe's queue access.

Here are my questions.
I don't have a clear ​understanding​ how to solve this problem by "setuid".

1. First, if the file is created by user printer, how does user joe copy data to a file owned by printer. Does it have some certain right to this file.
2. Secondly, how to identify the relationship between you and the file you queued.
3. Does the file's state show something, but the file is owned by printer, which can only be changed by root. Does it have something to do with the file's gid? If so, other users' gid may also be related to this file.
4. Does the file's context show something about who queued it?

My questions are a mess, and I really don't have a clear concept about the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume that the files are to be stored in `/var/spool/pq` directory; the permissions on the directory `printer:printgrp:2700` (owner `printer`, group `printgrp`, mode 2700 - read, write, execute for owner only, and the SGID bit set on the directory means all files created in it will belong to group `printgrp`).

Further, we assume that the print queuing program, `pq`, has permissions `printer:printgrp:4511` (setuid `printer`, anyone can execute it, but only `printer` or `root` can look at it).

Now, suppose Joe runs `pq /home/joe/file`, and the permissions on the file are `joe:staff:600` (only Joe can read or write to the file).  Joe's umask is set to 022 (though this file has more restrictive permissions than are implied by the umask).

When the program runs, the real UID of the process is `joe`, but the effective UID is `printer`.  Since there is no need for setgid operation here, both the real and effective GID are `staff`. Joe's auxilliary groups list does not include `printgrp`.

Note that it is the effective UID and GID of a process that control its access to files.  On his own, Joe cannot see what jobs are in the printer queue; the directory permissions shown don't even allow him to list the files, or access the files in the directory.  Note that the converse applies; on its own, the `printer` user (or the `pq` program running as that user) cannot access Joe's file.

The `pq` program can create files in the printer queue directory; it will probably create two files for this request.  One will be a control file, the other will be a copy of the file to be printed.  It will determine a job number by some mechanism (say 12345) and it might create and open two files for writing (with restrictive permissions - 0600 or even 0400):

- `/var/spool/pq/c.12345` - the control file
- `/var/spool/pq/d.12345.1` - the first (only) data file

It should then reset its effective UID to the real UID, so it is running as Joe.  It can then open the file Joe asked to be printed, and copy it to the data file.  It can also write whatever information it deems relevant to the control file (date, time, who submitted the request, the number of files to be printed, special printing options, etc).  When it closes those files, Joe is no longer able to access them.  But the program was able to copy Joe's file to its print queue.

So, that addresses questions 1 (permissions) and 2 (control information), and also 4 (control information again).

Regarding question 3, `root` is always a wild card on Unix-like systems because can do anything that he wants.  However, as suggested by the rest of the answer, the control file contains information about the print request, including (in particular) who submitted it.  You can use setgid programs instead of setuid programs; these work in analogous ways.  However, under the system I postulated, the group permissions essentially didn't come into the picture.  The `pq` program set the permissions on the control file and data file such that the group can't read it, and the directory permissions also deny group access.

We can postulate two more programs:

- `pqs` - printer queue status
- `pqr` - printer queue remove

These programs would also be setuid `printer`.  The `pqs` program can read the control files in the directory and list pertinent information from them.  The `pqr` program can read the control files to ensure that when Joe submitted job 12345 when he requests the removal of job 12345.  If the program is satisfied, then it can delete the files.

Separately from these user-invoked programs, there would also be a daemon program (conventionally named `pqd` in this system) that would be kicked into action by `pq` if it is not already running.  It would be responsible for reading the control files in the directory, and using that information to actually print the data files to the relevant printer.  The details of how different printers and different data formats are handled are a problem for the daemon to deal with.  The daemon too will run with `printer` privileges, and `printer` will have been given access to the printer devices (for locally attached printers) or configured to communicate over the network with a protocol such as IPP (Internet Printer Protocol).  Joe probably won't be able to use the printer devices directly.

Note that the setuid programs have powers that Joe does not have.  They must be written carefully to ensure that Joe cannot abuse those extra powers.  Any setuid program is somewhat dangerous; a setuid `root` program can be lethal.  In general, setgid programs are less dangerous.  However, for both types of program, great care is required in the writing of such programs.

Comment: Thank you for your gracious answer~, but I still have a small question, do you mean once the file opened by pq as user printer with the mode read or write, can it be accessed, read or writen as user joe too?

Comment: Yes: once the file descriptor is open, it does not matter that the program changes effective UID (or GID).  Reopening would be a different matter.  The program would probably check that Joe could access the files on the command line OK before it created the files in the spool area.  There are also some stunts you can pull switching back and forth (saved UID) so if Joe lists 500 files on the command line, you don't run out of file descriptors.  The outline is the basic mode of operation, though.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The preferred way of saying "Thanks" around here is by up-voting helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do that) and by accepting one of the answers as the most helpful.  There's a check-mark (tick) beside the answers.  When you accept an answer, you also get a small boost to your reputation.  Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoveflow.com/faq), especially [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).