# Is it possible to run a script as a different user (other then root) in unix without prompting for a pwd?

Tags: java, security, unix

I have a requirement wherein I am running a shell script from java code.
I have been using rsh for this purpose of running a script as a different user and getting back the control to the previous user after successful execution of the script.

Syntax used is :

```
rsh -l <username> unix cmd(script here)
```

Now due to some security reasons I have to use only sh for the above purpose.

My Requirements are:

1. Different users might run this script other than root and all have permissions to execute the same.
2. Users executing the script are many and the passwords cannot be obtained from the code and sent to the script to be run successfully.
3. The command should not prompt for the user password while executing this command.
4. I cannot update any config files with username to stop it from prmpting the password.

I have gone through the alternatives such as `ssh, su, sudo` etc. but in vain.

Please suggest some alternative to this requirement that will fulfill all the above conditions.

Comment: Simply ask them to execute your application with root permissions.

Comment: Please note that this script has to be run as a different user other than root. How can i ask them to run this with root when my primary objective is not to execute it with root?

Comment: Can you tell what is the purpose of using the script?

Comment: It will be calling a jar and executing some project specific operations that are not supposed to be revealed.

Comment: Could you solve this issue, @Galaxin?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a *NIX feature called `setuid` by setting

```
chmod +s your_file
```

You can find a great explanation in Jonathan Leffler's answer on [A usage of setuid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8754726/1983854).

To check if the script is being executed by `root` or not, you can check `$EUID`, that contains the ID of the user executing the script. If it is 0, it means `root` (and other users with root permissions).

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
```

From [How to: Check the bash shell script is being run by root or not](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-root-user-check-script.html)